# Which distortion pedals have a strong low and low-mid frequency response?

Tags: distortion

I'm looking for a distortion pedal to be used with various instruments that produce frequencies anywhere in the spectrum of 20 hz - 12,000+ hz.

I have guitar fuzz pedals that produce strong high end and high-mid distortions, but are lacking outside of that. What are some distortion pedals that produce a very audible effect on the low and low-mid frequency ranges (e.g. below 5000 hz)? True bypass in the switch is also desirable, but not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distortion effects work by introducing high frequency harmonics into a signal. This is even the case when distorting sound sources that only contain bass frequencies.

A bassy distortion sound is achieved by either filtering the high end out of the distorted output with any distortion pedals tone control turned right down. Or by blending the distortion effect with the original sound source or a low-pass filtered version of it (this is how bass distortion pedals work).

There are some distortion effect for the guitar which create a lower tone so called "sub-octave" effects but these only really work on single note sound sources so I don't think they are what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a bass distortion pedal, [like this one.](http://www.bestcovery.com/roger-mayer-voodoo-bass-2-dual-band-bass-pedal)